# How do you check a random number against multiple lists in Python?

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, random

I'm making a little text-based game in python for school. I also play a lot of runescape, so I wanted to incorporate some chance instead of just forcing interactions with monsters. I have four different rarites (common 1/5, uncommon 1/15, etc.) I want to roll at each part of the dungeon to determine the level/difficulty of the monster before I give the user their input.

I tried to make it as simple and consise as possible by putting the rarities and ther respective ranges in a dictionary and then using a for loop to catch the rarity from the randint roll, but I can't figure it out.

```
rolls = {'common': list(range(1, 6)), 'uncommon': list(range(6, 21)), 'rare': list(range(21, 46)), 'omg': list(range(46, 146))}
```

```
chance = random.randint(1,146)
for i in rolls:
    if i == chance:
        print(i)
```

I have tried variations of loops, I've googled a ton, and now I'm getting an error: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: if chance in rolls[i] works; that said, your rarities are in the wrong order :)

Comment: This is going to need to look for "if chance in rolls[i]:" although there are better ways to do it. Also your probabilities seem a off.

Answer (score 0):

Combining some of the earlier remarks:

1. Ensure that your 'rarities' are **correctly weighted**. If you want to assign ranges for the randomint, the most common result must have the largest weight.
2. There is **no need to create entire lists** of integers to evaluate the random value. It is sufficient to store the beginning or the end value of each these ranges in order to evaluate further.

the resulting code can be something like:

```py
from random import randint

# store for every label the end of the range
chance_labels = [
    ('common', 20),
    ('uncommon', 27),
    ('rare', 31),
    ('omg', 32)
]

# get the second value from the last tuple in chance_labels (32) is the max value to be 'rolled'
max_randint = chance_labels[-1][1] 

chance = randint(1, max_randint)

# get the first tuple from chance_labels for which 'chance' is smaller than the end of the range
label = next(label for label, range_end in chance_labels if chance <= range_end)
print(f'{chance}: {label}')
```

**note** that in order to get a 1/5 chance of something to happen ('common' in your example), the other options must add up to 4/5. Meaning that the sum of the other chances must be 4 times bigger.